# Ansible fact for systemd available on target system

Tags: ansible, ansible-facts

I'm wondering whether there is a way to find out which service manager is used on the target system through Ansible facts. I can only find modules to gather facts about running services but not about the type of service manager.

I need to install some services on a system and in case there is `systemd` available, I would like to make use of `systemd`'s dependency management and composition feature explicitly.

Comment: You can just [look for the directory `/run/systemd/system`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/sd_booted.html). If it exists, the system was booted using systemd.

Answer (score 1):

> *I'm wondering whether there is a way to find out which service manager is used on the target system through Ansible facts.*

Yes, it seems that [Ansible Facts](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_vars_facts.html#ansible-facts) are providing already the information

> *I can only find modules to gather facts about running services but not about the type of service manager.*

namely via the key:value `"ansible_service_mgr": "systemd"`.

Another option could be the [`service_facts`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/service_facts_module.html) module. According the [Returned Facts](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/service_facts_module.html#returned-facts) the key

> *`source`: Init system of the service. One of `rcctl`, `systemd`, `sysv`, `upstart`, `src`. Returned: always*

By checking the value of one of it you may be able to implement your conditional dependency management.

According fact naming options [Why should I remove the `ansible_` prefix when refering to an Ansible fact?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73860415/6771046) it would lead to [Conditionals based on `ansible_facts`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_conditionals.html#conditionals-based-on-ansible-facts) in example like

```yaml
when: ansible_facts.service_mgr == "systemd"
```

---

**Minimal Example**

```yaml
---
- hosts: localhost
  become: false
  gather_facts: true
  gather_subset:
    - "min"

  tasks:

  - name: Show Facts
    debug:
      msg: "{{ ansible_facts.service_mgr }}"
```

will result into an output of

```yaml
TASK [Show Facts] ******
ok: [localhost] =>
  msg: systemd
```

**Further Q&A**

- [What is the exact list of Ansible `setup` `min`?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71061125/6771046)

Comment: thanks a lot @U880D. I simply overlooked this property of standard facts.